# How to update OJS

Tags: open-source, web, journal

Would you please let me know how to update OJS (Open Journal System). I have installed it on a shared server and I have no access to the shell, only a web interface and control panel (direct admin) is allowed. I think there must be some update button online, But i could not find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download and decompress the package from the OJS web site
- Make a copy of the config.inc.php provided in the new package
- Move or copy the following files and directories from your current OJS
  installation:

  - config.inc.php
  - public/
  - Your uploaded files directory ("files_dir" in config.inc.php), if it
    resides within your OJS directory
- Replace the current OJS directory with the new OJS directory, moving the
  old one to a safe location as a backup
- Be sure to review the Configuration Changes section of the release notes
  in docs/release-notes/README-(version) for all versions between your
  original version and the new version. You may need to manually add
  new items to your config.inc.php file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to make a new folder on your shared hosts with the latest version. Copy over the config.ing.php, cache, and public folders. If your files is within your OJS folder as well, copy it too (though, you should move it outside the web accessible location).

Then you'll find an option to upgrade the database in the Admin pages.